# Abort Javascript so other function isn't called

Tags: javascript

I have no idea if this is even possible, but I thought I would ask since it would be awesome if it is possible.

So basically I have a link with an onclick and in the onclick there are two calls. one to a function and another to _doPostBack.

The first function that is called is a simple function:

```
function CheckTerms() {

    if (!document.Form.agreetoterms.checked) {
        alert("Please check the terms and conditions.");
        return false;
    }
        return true;
}
```

So basically if the check box isnt checked the alert happens and the page doesn't submit. If it is checked it submits. Right now even if it isn't checked, it shows the alert and executes the doPostBack and submits the page. The doPostBack is put into the link dynamically and I don't have access to it, which has made it harder for me. So any ideas or ways to abort it so it doesn't submit?

Thanks!

Comment: But you can modify the function which calls both `CheckTerms` and `doPostBack`? If so, insert: `if(!CheckTerms()) { return false;}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the `_doPostback` function handles the posting of the form, and that you **don't** want the anchor to move the page to the location of its `href` when clicked.  `preventDefault` does this by preventing the anchor's default action from being taken when clicked.

```
var a = document.getElementById("yourAnchorId");
a.onclick = function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   if (CheckTerms())
      _doPostBack();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why can't you do the following:

```
function CheckTerms() {

    if (!document.Form.agreetoterms.checked) {
        alert("Please check the terms and conditions.");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        <<< call you function here >>>
    }
        return true;
}
```